# Zune Last-day-of-leap-year bug - did Microsoft release a fix?

Tags: zune, patch

When the Zune 30's had the outage on the last day of 2008, there was a side discussion about how long it would take for Microsoft to create a fix.

After the dust settled, the problem "fixed itself" because the problem was only for one day. However, some other people found the offending code, and it looks like this problem will happen every four years.

I went looking around (google + Microsoft Zune site), and I could not find any reference that says this problem was fixed in code and released.

Has anyone seen a documented fix from Microsoft?

Answer (score 2):

Since it only affected the older Zune 30 model, MS did not bother to release a fix.  The Zune 30's resumed operation on the following day (Jan 1), so the fix was just to wait a day.  If this issue occurred with a newer zune model (especially one that was still under warranty), they probably would've taken the time to fix it.

The next leap year is 2012, so it's questionable how many Zune 30's will still be in service at that time. I know my Zune 30 is nearing the end of its life, as its battery can only hold about a 15-30 minute charge these days after being used regularly for about 3 years.